# MultiBinding as resource and not Style in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a button that performs a command on an object.
I want to assign the same command to some mouse event.

Currently the button is setup like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding MoveItemsCommand, ElementName=SelectListControl}">
    <Button.CommandParameter>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ZipConverter}">
            <Binding Source="{x:Static local:MoveItemDirection.Up}" />
            <Binding ElementName="ListViewDestination" Path="SelectedItems" />
            <Binding ElementName="ListViewDestination" Path="ItemsSource" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </Button.CommandParameter>
    <!-- ... -->
</Button>
```

Is there a way to reuse that `MultiBinding` when I define the mouse event?

I cannot create a `Style` with the `MultiBinding` as the style needs to target a type and the mouse event would be of an incompatible type. So I'm asking for a workaround that would plug into the workaround I'm following for the mouse event - http://blog.lanwin.de/2010/01/28/apply-command-inputbindings-on-styles/

L.E. oh, the `ZipConverter` thing is nothing really special, just some workaround one needs to use when passing multiple parameters to commands:

```
public class ZipConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) =>
        values.Clone();

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, @mm8, this sort of helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to reuse that MultiBinding...

No, each control needs to have its *orders* listed and there is no way to centralize those commands / styles.